# Laravel - regex route match everything but not exactly one or more word

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I make a route like

```
Route::get('/{url1}', function ($url1) {
    return ' url1: '.$url1;
})
->where('url1', '^(?!(string1|string2)$)');
```

and access url like:
- `domain/abc` **not found => incorrect** ??
- `domain/string1` not found => correct

and more, when i do with

```
Route::get('/{url1}/{url2}', function ($url1) {
    return ' url1: '.$url1;
})
->where('url1', '^(?!(string1|string2)$)');
```

and access url like: 
- `domain/abc/abc` **not found => incorrect** ??? 
- `domain/string1/abc` not found => correct

How to fix that thank

Comment: In where string will be static or dynamic ?

Comment: @MiteshRathod string1 and string2 is special word (it's static)

Comment: only this 2 string not accept in url, correct ?

Comment: @MiteshRathod yes, string1 or string2 will be not accept in url

Comment: Please add your exact regular expression.

Answer (score 4):

Please try with this
for 1st scenario:

```
Route::get('/{url1}', function ($url1) {
    return ' url1: '.$url1;
})->where('url1', '^!(string1|string2)$');
```

for 2nd scenario:

```
Route::get('/{url1}/{url2}', function ($url1, $url2) {
    return ' url1: '.$url1 . ' url2: '.$url2;
})->where('url1', '^!(string1|string2)$');
```

i hope this help :)

Comment: thankiu but, i just try 1st  with `domain/abc` but it's not found?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 Route::get('{url1}', function ($url1) {
    return ' url1: '.$url1;
})->where('url1','^(?!string1$|string2$)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)');
```

Unclean way to achieve this

```
Route::get('{url1}/{url2?}', function ($url1,$url2 = null) {
        if ($url2 == "string1" || $url2 == "string2" || $url1 == "string1" || $url1 == "string2") {
            return "false";
        } else {
            return "true";
        }
});
```

One more way I have tried in by using `RouteServiceProvider.php`

Change your `boot()` like this.

```
public function boot()
    {
        //
        Route::pattern('url1', '^(?!string1$|string2$)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)');
        Route::pattern('url2', '^(?!string1$|string2$)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)');
        parent::boot();
    }
```

Comment: thankiu, but it not working well. I just try `domain/string1` => it still found

Comment: @DeLe strange I have tried same code, but it`s excluding `http://127.0.0.1:8000/domain/string2`, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/domain/string1` and working for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/domain/abc`

Comment: sorry for `domain`, `domain` like `http://127.0.0.1:8000` and you should try `127.0.0.1:8000/string1`, ...

Comment: @DeLe Updated, check now.

Comment: it working for one url but in my second case like `Route::get('{url1}/{url2}', function ($url1, $url2) {
    return ' url1: '.$url1.' url2: '.$url2;
})->where('url1','^(?!string1$|string2$)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)');`. I try `http://domain/string1/a` it still found ?

Comment: @DeLe Could not find a clean of doing this, but update code will work for you case.

Comment: @DeLe Check  out updated answer by using `RouteServiceProvider`.

Answer (score 3):

After tests I think it's impossible to achieve exactly what you want. It seems when you want to exclude `string1` and `string2` you need to agree that also strings starting with `string1` and `string2` will be excluded (so for example `string1aaa`).

When using such routes:

```
Route::get('/{url1}', function ($url1) {
    return ' url1: '.$url1;
})->where('url1', '(?!string1|string2)[^\/]+');


Route::get('/{url1}/{url2}', function ($url1, $url2) {
    return ' url1: '.$url1. ' # '.$url2;
})->where('url1', '(?!string1|string2)[^\/]+');
```

result will be:

```
domain/abc - found, correct
domain/string1 - not found, correct
domain/abc/abc - found, correct
domain/string1/abc - not found, correct
domain/string1aaa - not found, I believe you need to accept this
domain/string1aaa/abc - not found, I believe you need to accept this
```

I believe such limitation comes from Laravel and not from regex. If you need to accept also parameters starting with `string1` and `string2` I believe you need to do it in manual way like so:

```
Route::get('/{url1}', function ($url1) {
    if (!preg_match('#^(?!string1$|string2$)[^\/]*$#', $url1)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    return ' url1: '.$url1;
});


Route::get('/{url1}/{url2}', function ($url1, $url2) {
    if (!preg_match('#^(?!string1$|string2$)[^\/]*$#', $url1)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    return ' url1: '.$url1. ' # '.$url2;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```php
    Route::get('/{url1}', function ($url1) {
        return 'url: '.url1;
    })->where('url1', '^(?!(string1|string2)$)(\S+)');
```

Comment: thankiu, but when i try `http://domain/string1/abc` it still found?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than writing a route to match anything *other than* certain static strings, I find it clearer to write two routes: one route to match certain static strings, and another route to match everything else.

```
// route that matches forbidden static strings, optionally with a postfix slug
$router->get('/{forbidden}/{optional_path?}', function () {
    return response('Not found', 404);
})->where([ 'forbidden' => '(?:string1|string2)', 'optional_path' => '.*' ]);

// route that matches anything else (order of definition matters, must be last)
// might also consider using Route::fallback(), but I prefer to leave that
// alone in case my future self changes this below and opens up a hole
$router->get('/{anything?}', function () {
    return response('Found', 200);
})->where([ 'anything' => '.*' ]);
```

Which results in<sup>*</sup>:

- `domain` => 200 Found
- `domain/` => 200 Found
- `domain/abc` => 200 Found
- `domain/string1` => 404 Not found
- `domain/string1/` => 404 Not found
- `domain/string1/abc` => 404 Not found
- `domain/string10` => 200 Found
- `domain/string10/` => 200 Found
- `domain/string10/abc` => 200 Found
- `domain/string2` => 404 Not found
- `domain/string2/` => 404 Not found
- `domain/string2/abc` => 404 Not found
- `domain/string20` => 200 Found
- `domain/string20/` => 200 Found
- `domain/string20/abc` => 200 Found

I find this more clear, because I don't have to think in terms of exclusions. Rather, I can think of matching exactly what I want to forbid, then letting Laravel react to everything else (fail open policy). This may not meet your design criteria, but I do believe it results in clearer code.

Also, the code is more performant. `?!` has to backtrack, which is by definition more expensive than forward matching.

I don't have a Laravel environment to hand, but I'll hazard a guess as to why your attempts didn't work. Laravel uses Symfony Router, which [does not support lookarounds on slugs](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10548). IIRC, when a lookaround's detected, Symfony applies the lookaround to the entire URL, not the slug you've bound the pattern to. This messes with the developer's idea of how anchors (^, $) and greedy (*) meta characters work. This can lead to a bad experience in trying to get it to work, since the developer's operating under one assumption but the underlying libraries operating on another.

---

<sup>*</sup> Full disclosure, I wrote this for Lumen then mentally converted it to Laravel format. It's possible there are some translation errors. Here's the original Lumen:

```
$router->get('/{forbidden:(?:string1|string2)}[/{optional_path:.*}]', function () {
    return response('Not found', 404);
});
$router->get('{anything:.*}', function () {                                   
    return response('Found', 200);
});
```